# Converting Unix Time into Human Readable Format in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

I have a spreadsheet containing several timestamp columns, given in Unix time, i.e. number of seconds since 01/01/1970 00:00.00 UTC.

Using Excel 2010, are there any methods, and if so how, to convert these timestamps into a date/time format recognizable by Excel?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
value / 86400 + "1/1/1970"
```

Division by 86400 is needed to convert it into days (product of 24 * 60 * 60), you then add the number of days between 1st Jan 1900 (which is where Excel bases its dates off) and 1st of Jan 1970.

Comment: +1: I prefer (timestamp / 86400 + 25569) but they're the same thing. Format the field as date/time and you're good to go.

Comment: & @Satanicpuppy: +1 - Confirmed both methods work and produce identical results using the Unix Time entry at Wikipedia.  Properly implemented, the formulas should translate 1299098490 to 03/02/2011 @ 20:41:30 Zulu after formatting the cell to date/time.

Comment: Only works if your locale is set to "DD/MM/YYYY", whereas other people have it as "YYYY/MM/DD", then you have to use the localized date format.  Rather use `DATE(1970,1,1)`